# sql select with php variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out a html-table from db-table 'dimensions'. I only want dimensions from the selected pipetype which I get from a dropdownbox. For now I just put in "Steel" manually. Steel has pipe_id = 2 in db-table 'pipes'.

I've run the first query in my db-tool and it returns 2 so there's nothing wrong there. The second query returns nothing. But when I manually set $wq = 2 (which I comment out below) it prints out the html-table perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$wq="SELECT pipe_id FROM pipes WHERE title_en = 'Steel'";
//$wq = '2';

$sql="SELECT * FROM dimensions WHERE  pipe_id = '".$wq."'";
```

Comment: You're not executing any query there. Here's a tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: how are you querying the database from PHP? I don't think you can get values into `$wq` like that

Comment: I think a join might make more sense here, I don't think you can nest your SELECT statements in that fashion.

Comment: Yeah, are you using PHP commands to send this request to the database? Are you properly setting the $wq param higher up in the code. The query itself looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this simple subquery instead:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM dimensions WHERE pipe_id = 
    (SELECT pipe_id FROM pipes WHERE title_en = 'Steel');
```

Comment: Works! I'm new with php, been using ms access before and I always nested my queries. Guess that dosen't work in php =) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd try something more like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dimensions AS A, pipe_id AS B WHERE B.title_en='Steel' AND A.pipe_id=B.pipe_id';
```

Answer (score -1):

### 1.

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM 
    dimensions AS d
    INNER JOIN pipes AS p ON
        p.pipe_id = d.pipe_id AND
        p.title_en = 'Steel'
```

### 2.

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM (
    dimensions AS d,
    pipes AS p
)
WHERE
    p.pipe_id = d.pipe_id AND
    p.title_en = 'Steel'
```

### 3.

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    dimensions AS d
WHERE
    d.pipe_id = (
        SELECT p.pipe_id
        FROM pipes AS p
        WHERE p.title_en = 'Steel'
        LIMIT 1
    )
```